# why is the css class not applied

Tags: css

```
.pitch h1
{
    FONT-FAMILY: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 40px; LETTER-SPACING: -0.03em; FONT-SIZE: 60px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; WORD-SPACING: -0.04em; color:#FFFFFF;
    LETTER-SPACING: -0.05em;
}
```

the html:

```
  <h1 class="pitch">
                Best way to increase client's<br>
                confidence and boost your sales</h1>
```

what is wrong here?
why is this class not applied? Insteed of applying class .pitch , it applies the frmat of the body text to the text inside h1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.pitch h1` means "find an element of type h1 that is a child of an element with class 'pitch'".

What you want is `h1.pitch`.

Comment: what would mean (#pitch h1 a) and (.pitch h1 a)? This would make me understand it. Please tell me.

Comment: # means ID, . means class, so (#pitch h1 a) means find element of type a that is a child of an element of type h1 that is a child of an element with an ID of pitch.  (.pitch h1 a) means the same thing except it's looking for an element with a class of pitch.

Answer (score 3):

The `h1` isn't in some other element with the class `pitch`, which is what your CSS is trying to apply the rule to. Instead, the `h1` **has that class**.

If you want to select the `h1` with the class, use `h1.pitch`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.pitch h1 { ... }`, i think it should just be `.pitch`.

Comment: I think `h1.pitch` would be more correct, as there could be other element types with class pitch that should not receive the style.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the attributes for `h1` that belongs to `.pitch` class like -

```
.pitch h1{ ... }

<div class="pitch">
   <h1>   </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `h1.pitch` would be more correct, as there could be other element types with class `pitch` that should not receive the style.

Comment: @JamesAllardice - Got you. Modified. Thanks.